# Create an array of Strings which are initialized to the 7 days of the week

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, dayofweek

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {

//Create an array of Strings which are initialized to the 7 days of the week using a while-loop, print all the contents of the array. (do the same for do-while and for loop)

```
  String days[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
  
  
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are correct if what you meant was that there is a subtle error in your code. I didn’t see it until I read the *last* line of the correct answer by Elliot Frisch. Therefore: when asking about an error in your program, *always paste the error message into your question*. It will allow more people to understand the question and the error and hence answer. See more here: [ask].

Comment: Googling for "java initialize array of strings" gave me the duplink.  The top two answers answer your question.

Comment: Your answer is here: [Help - Syntax error on token "=", Name expected after token](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1261128/help-syntax-error-on-token-name-expected-after-token).

Comment: @StephenC I uphold that it’s a very poor original for this question. I admit it’s hard to be sure because the question isn’t there, but I believe that this question is about a very specific syntax error which is not covered in the linked question. And I also agree that closing this question as a duplicate is likely to be more helpful than closing as needing debugging details or downright unclear (which would arguably be more correct and deserved).

Comment: You may need this array for an exercise that specifically excludes better alternatives (in which case the answer below gives you what you need). For a real-world program do not create such an array. Java knows the days of the week. If you need an array of them get it from `DayOfWeek.values()`. And if and when you need to print the name to your user, get it from the `getDisplayName` method of each element of the array you got.

Comment: If you can find a better >>StackOverflow<< duplink, please add it.  But it is a matter of semantics.  Do you interpret this as a "how do I initialize an array?" ... as per the title, or "how do I fix the syntax error in this code?" ... which the OP didn't bother to tell anyone about.  Frankly, I don't really think it matters.  It is a poor question (for many reasons) and hopefully the Roomba will clear it out.

Comment: @StephenC Well said. And definitely the latter (in spite of the ambiguity).

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** use `{}` not `()`.

You forgot to ask a question, but the array initialization syntax is

```
String days[] = new String[] {
        "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
        "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
};
```

And can be shortened to

```
String days[] = {
        "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
        "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
};
```

And the prefered way (in Java) has the array type with the name of the class. So,

```
String[] days = {
        "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
        "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
};
```